# Can I get the signature of a C# delegate by its type?

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates

Is there a straightforward way using reflection to get at the parameter list for a delegate if you have its type information?

For an example, if I declare a delegate type as follows

```
delegate double FooDelegate (string param, bool condition);
```

and later get the type information for that delegate type as follows

```
Type delegateType = typeof(FooDelegate);
```

Is it possible to retrieve the return type (double) and parameter list ({string, bool}) from that type info object?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

```
    MethodInfo method = delegateType.GetMethod("Invoke");
    Console.WriteLine(method.ReturnType.Name + " (ret)");
    foreach (ParameterInfo param in method.GetParameters()) { 
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", param.ParameterType.Name, param.Name);
    }
```

Comment: Perfect!  Digging deeper, the reason this works is that declaring the delegate is basically syntax sugar for declaring a class derived from Delegate with a new Invoke method that takes the specified parameters.

Thanks for the help.