# Reflection - Add a Delegate to another Delegate's invocation list

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates

i am attempting to attach a Delegate to an invocation list of a different delegate. 
By that i am achieving a kind of Hook on existing events.
I need to hook up something that runs after each event that is invoked.

The following example **works** as long as the Delegate exposed by the type and the Action i pass in have the exact same signature. 
(On1 and OnAll events are both declared with an Action delegate so it works).

Code :  How i hook up an Action with an existing delegate exposed by an event modifier.

```
public static class ReflectionExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<EventInfo> GetEvents(this object obj)
    {
        var events = obj.GetType().GetEvents();
        return events;
    }

    public static void AddHandler(this object obj, Action action)
    {
        var events = obj.GetEvents();
        foreach (var @event in events)
        {                    
             @event.AddEventHandler(obj, action);
        }
    }
}
```

The Sample :

```
public class Tester 
{
    public event Action On1;
    public event Action On2;

    public void RaiseOn1()
    {
        On1();
    }

    public void RaiseOn2()
    {
        On2();
    }
}   

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var t = new Tester();
        t.On1 += On1;
        t.On2 += On2;

        t.AddHandler(OnAll);

        t.RaiseOn1();
        t.RaiseOn2();
    }

    public void On1() { }
    public void On2() { }
    public void OnAll() { }
}
```

**The Problem** : When the Delegate exposed with an event modifier in Tester does not have the same signature i get a well wanted and obvious exception which states (in my words) **that `Action` can't be added to an invocation list of an `Action<int>`** . makes sense.

Just to be clear I'm describing the following :

```
    public event Action<int> On1;    
    public void On1(int i){}
```

What I'm looking for is a way to create another Delegate of the same type as the EventHandlerType. In order to do that i need to create a method with the signature i of EventHandlerType which would internally invoke action.

something like :

```
 public static void AddHandler(this object obj, Action action)
 {
      var events = obj.GetEvents();
      foreach (var @event in events)
      {
          // method with the signeture of EventHandlerType which does action();
          MethodInfo wrapperMethod = WrapAction(@event.EventHandlerType, action);

          Delegate handler = Delegate.CreateDelegate(@event.EventHandlerType, action.Target, wrapperMethod);
          @event.AddEventHandler(obj, handler);
      }
 }
```

Comment: You want to pass an `Action<int>` as an `Action` and add them inside `AddHandler`?

Comment: I want to invoke an action (yes of type Action for the sake of argument) every time any @event's underlying delegate is invoked. 
Ive described what i attempted but  any solution would be most welcome.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This seems to work... There are various comments inside... I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it. I'm building an `Expression` tree to do the delegate invocation.

```
public static void AddHandler(this object obj, Action action)
{
    var events = obj.GetEvents();

    foreach (var @event in events)
    {
        // Simple case
        if (@event.EventHandlerType == typeof(Action))
        {
            @event.AddEventHandler(obj, action);
        }
        else
        {
            // From here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/429564/613130
            // We retrieve the parameter types of the event handler
            var parameters = @event.EventHandlerType.GetMethod("Invoke").GetParameters();

            // We convert it to ParameterExpression[]
            ParameterExpression[] parameters2 = Array.ConvertAll(parameters, x => Expression.Parameter(x.ParameterType));

            MethodCallExpression call;

            // Note that we are "opening" the delegate and using
            // directly the Target and the Method! Inside the 
            // LambdaExpression we will build there won't be a 
            // delegate call, there will be a method call!
            if (action.Target == null)
            {
                // static case
                call = Expression.Call(action.Method);
            }
            else
            {
                // instance type
                call = Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(action.Target), action.Method);
            }

            // If you are OK to create a delegate that calls another
            // delegate, you can:
            // call = Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(action), typeof(Action).GetMethod("Invoke"));
            // instead of the big if/else

            var lambda = Expression.Lambda(@event.EventHandlerType, call, parameters2);
            @event.AddEventHandler(obj, lambda.Compile());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was working on a similar answer but you beat me to it :) great implementation.

Comment: Amazing :) 10x allot .