# Generic delegate hook

Tags: c#, delegates

I have a generic functions framework wrapping a Jint engine (provides C# functions usage in JavaScript). The C# functions are registered like so (example for LOG function registration):

```
    private void RegisterUtils()
    {
        this.RegisterFunction("LOG", new Action<int, object>((level, message) =>
        {
            Logger.WriteLine(level, message);
        }));
        //....
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Register framework function.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name"></param>
    /// <param name="body"></param>
    internal void RegisterFunction(string name, Delegate body)
    {
        this.JintEngine.SetValue(name, body);
    }
```

I can assume the delegate is always Action or Func.

I want to **add logic** to that delegate in RegisterFunction (for example saving the name in a context object).

Looks like delegates have something called invokation list. I tried this:

```
Delegate.Combine(new Action(() => { /*logic here*/ }), body)
```

But got "ArgumentException: Delegates must be of the same type." Creating a new delegate using the type requires having a function matching the signarute, which is impossible dynamically.

I've seen other questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30301751/reflection-add-a-delegate-to-another-delegates-invocation-list), and also an MSDN [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228976(v=vs.110).aspx) talking about hooking events (in WinForms etc.), but for that I need the type that throws the events (and a real method it seems).

Is there no way to add a simple Action to the delegate **itself**? Or wrap it somehow?

Comment: Did you find anything on this here useful yet by chance --> [Question](https://superuser.com/questions/1220455/taskkill-the-process-not-found)?