# C# Get Type Parameters from a Delegate which is a Func<>

Tags: c#, delegates, func

Say I've cast a Func<> to a Delegate, for example...

```
Func<object, int> func = GetFunc();
Delegate d = func;
```

Now, if I know the type of Delegate ahead of time, I can cast directly back to Func<>

```
Func<object, int> newFunc = (Func<object, int>)d;
```

But what if I don't know the function type until runtime? How do I get back my Func<> from a Delegate?

```
Delegate d = GetFunc(); // may return a Func<T>, Func<T,T2>, Func<T,T2,T3>, etc...
var func = GetFuncFromDelegate(d);
```

or at least, get the Type parameters so I can rebuild the type:

```
Delegate d = GetFunc(); // may return a Func<T>, Func<T,T2>, Func<T,T2,T3>, etc...
Type[] funcParams = GetTypeParamsFromDelegate(d);
```

Comment: Potentially useful reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/429552/can-i-get-the-signature-of-a-c-sharp-delegate-by-its-type

Comment: +1 Gave me exactly what I needed. Thanks! I'll post a full-code answer once I'm finished, if no one else beats me to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> or at least, get the Type parameters so I can rebuild the type:

This one is as simple as:

```
Type[] funcParams = (d.GetType()).GenericTypeArguments;
```

Comment: This works, though I definitely like CollinD's link, which also gives me the names of the parameters `foreach (ParameterInfo param in method.GetParameters())`